# Verifying text box content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textbox

I have this javascript function:

```
function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        log("Field is empty");
    } else {
        log( 'You: ' + field.val);
        log( 'You2: ' + field.val);
        send(field.val);
        $('#message').val('');
    }
}
```

And this html text box and button:

```
<input type="text" id='message'>
<button type="button" onclick="checkTextField(this);">Send</button>
```

Any Ideas why it's not checking properly if the box is empty?
It always gives the if's output, never the else's one.

Comment: Because the passed `this` refers to the `button`, not to the `input`.

Comment: Thanks, but what to replace the `(this)` with. I tried `(message)`, but it work's only when the box is empty, otherwise it's logging undefined.

Comment: Why to pass anything? You could just use `$('#message')`, as you've done at the end of the `else` block. Or if you've more these kind of pairs, pass an `id`, and use it as a selector.

Comment: Yes, i tried `$('#message')` too but it was only logging a lot of error javascript code(not part of mine).

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle with your code. and edit it into the qs ? there is confusion in what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="message">
<button type="button" onclick="checkTextField();">Send</button>

function checkTextField() {
    var value = $('#message').val();

    if (value === '') {
        log("Field is empty");
    } else {
        log( 'You: ' + value);
        log( 'You2: ' + value);
        send(value);
        $('#message').val('');
    }
}
```

As the **Teemu** said, you're passing the button to the function. You have to grab the value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comment stating the wrong use of this, you can also call the

```
document.getElementbyId()
```

function

Usage Examples : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: This is working only when the box is empty, otherwise it's still logging undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This quick JS function is checking if the field is empty or not (using pure JS)

```
<input type="text" id="sometext" value="" />
<input type="button" id="check" onclick="check();" value="Check if empty" />

function check() {
    if(document.getElementById("sometext").value == '') {
        alert('Field is empty');
    }
    else {
        alert('Field is not empty');
    }
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle to see it working https://jsfiddle.net/yqnrut94/

Cheers!